# What's the shortest way to check the value of a specific key in all nested objects

Tags: javascript, object

I need to check if any of the objects has a valid property value of false. I managed to get it working with a loop, but I'm trying to find a shorter way to do it.

```
let test_object = {
   "file": {
      "filetype": {
         "value": "png",
         "valid": true
      },
      "height": {
         "value": "250 px",
         "valid": true
      },
      "width": {
         "value": "970 px",
         "valid": true
      },
      "file_size": {
         "value": "5 kb",
         "valid": true
      },
      "duration": {
         "value": "-",
         "valid": true
      }
   }
};

let file_valid;
if (test_object != '') {
   for (const file_values of Object.values(test_object.file)) {
      if (file_values.valid == false) {
         file_valid = 'invalid'
      } else {
         file_valid = 'valid'
      }
   }
} else {
   file_valid = 'invalid'
}
```

Comment: I’d look for _correct_ code, before I start looking for _shorter_ code. What you have currently shown, does not determine whether _any_ of the objects has valid=false, but it will give you the result based on looking at the _last_ object, because you are overwriting `file_valid` in each loop iteration. You’d need to break out of the loop after you found the first invalid object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your requirements right, it should be something like this:

```js
let test_object = {
  "file": {
    "filetype": {
      "value": "png",
      "valid": true
    },
    "height": {
      "value": "250 px",
      "valid": true
    },
    "width": {
      "value": "970 px",
      "valid": true
    },
    "file_size": {
      "value": "5 kb",
      "valid": true
    },
    "duration": {
      "value": "-",
      "valid": true
    }
  }
};

/* 
 * if test_object is truthy AND
 * it DOES NOT have any attribute which is not valid (e.g. filetype.valid = false)
 * file_valid is set to 'valid' otherwise it is set to 'invalid'
 */
const file_valid = test_object && !Object.values(test_object.file).some(attribute => attribute.valid === false) ?
  'valid' :
  'invalid';

// test
console.log(file_valid);
```